# How can i install auto update my django database?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-rest-framework, axios

I add some data from public API to my sqlite database in views.py. And transmit it with django rest framework to axios (vuejs application display this data). Public API updated every second, i want run my views.py code every time as well to update my database automaticly.

I tried write some rough code like:

```
While True:
    #my views.py function
    time.sleep(30).
```

Can axios have a function to launch views.py code, or some inner django function to run my code?

Answer (score 0):

Simple putting while loop with sleep inside Your code will fail.

This seems to be easy, but it's complicated subject. I suggest to read about Celery and RabbitMQ, and how to use them with Django. Here is good entry point with examples how to do it:

https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/

I had similar task - create backend that will periodicaly ask URL, and write given data. I don't want to use Celery and RabbitMQ so i create async worker. It's not the best solution, but it works good for simple case:

https://github.com/t1waz/gwp_t1waz/blob/master/gwp/common/worker.py

Put Your code for getting data into Worker main_loop() inside while True loop.
Run start_background_worker() in urls.py file similar like in my project.

Cheers, Fenrir